# Russian (Cyrillic) characters not displaying in Orchard 1.6

Tags: orchardcms-1.6

I am trying to setup the multilingual orchard website with MySQL and the localization module. I’ve found that I cannot create the localized pages in Russian as the characters display ??? in the title when I try to save.
How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Andrii](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/protandr) the issue can be resolved by adding charset=utf8; at the end of MySql connection string. See the answer [here](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/443333).